# How many hit to database for one-to-many query using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having one-to-many relationship between Employee and Department and my class is looking like :

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
@Id
private int empId;
private String empName;
@OneToMany
@JoinTable (name = "relationalTable" , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "empId"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "deptId"))
private Collection <Department> dept = new ArrayList<Department>();

public int getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}
public void setEmpId(int empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}

public Collection<Department> getDept() {
    return dept;
}
public void setDept(Collection<Department> dept) {
    this.dept = dept;
}


@Column 
public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}
public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}
}
```

and my department class like :

```
@Entity
public class Department {
   int deptId;
   String deptName;
   private Employee emp;

   @ManyToOne
   public Employee getEmp() {
      return emp;
   }

   public void setEmp(Employee emp) {
      this.emp = emp;
   }

   @Id
   public int getDeptId() {
      return deptId;
   }

   public void setDeptId(int deptId) {
      this.deptId = deptId;
   }

   @Column
   public String getDeptName() {
      return deptName;
   }

   public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
      this.deptName = deptName;
   }
}
```

If I fetch the Department. So it will fetch all the employee at the same time associated with it. say with department id 1 there are 1000 employee. 
So how many queries will execute at this time to database to fetch all the data?

Comment: It would probably be lazy loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't specified the fetch type, then one-to-many relationships are by default lazy loaded. so your Employee class has one to many Departments.

so if you u load 1000 Employees, then there will be 1000 calls to load departments (1 call per each Employee).

what i cant understand your relationships,in this organization one department can have only one Employee but one Employee can work on few departments which is strange.

Comment: agree ... one 'Department' should have n employees so the relationship mentioned in problem ideally should be reversed

Answer (score 0):

IF the fetchType was Lazy Hibernate retrieve the record when you try to access the departments

If its eager Hibernate join all the queries into one queries and execute one query.